# How do I change the sprite shape within this open source iPhone game?

Tags: iphone, ipad

I downloaded the open source example game [iSpacies](http://www.karmatoad.co.uk/?p=43) and am trying to understand its design.

For example, how would you go about changing the alien image into a 'V' shape and the the fighter object image into a shape like this: '^'?

Comment: You should be clearer that you are doing game programming. At the first thought, I think you ask how to play that game:)

Comment: no i want to develop this for personal  improvement  in game making tach.this not for playing that game

Comment: I cleaned up the question to point out exactly what you are asking, but I still think this might be too localized of a question.  Maybe if you can point out what part of the process you are having difficulty with we might be able to help you out.  We're not going to read through an entire application's code to figure out your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mmmm this code seems using some king of game Engine.

But for your question, see the ispacies.png png file. It contains all enemies image :-)
But if you modify the image you will (probably) need to change some kind of variable in the program (I didn't find where).

But he's using OpenGL ES to do animations. You can to try using Core Animation with UIViewImage and CALayer :-)

Good Luck !

Comment: thanks for help it's working but I want each row of alien should  have a  different color .

Comment: Mmmm maybe the best way to achieve this is to add a function to UIImage to change the pixels color. But it needs to find out where and how are created aliens ;-)

Comment: And I want to move the fighter object only on the button(left-right) pressed when ever i pressed left it move to left side & whenever i click the right button it move to right side . And it must shoot  whenever i Click the shoot(fire) button